# Error while naming unnamed columns in Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, unnamed-module

Using this code to name the first column in the dataframe:
`df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0' : 'time'}, inplace=True)`
This gives me NoneType object.

I tried removing `inplace=True`  but then it just gives back the dataframe just like the original. No update in column name.

Comment: It still doesn't update the column name.

Comment: For the first column, yes!
```df1.columns
Out[75]: 
Index(['Unnamed: 0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'], dtype='object')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing,

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0' : 'time'}, inplace=False)
```

or

```
df1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0' : 'time'}, inplace=True)
```

Note the column name is `Unnamed: 0` (note the space)

Comment: Ah, right. Unnoticed mistake. It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ankita Considering accepting to close the answer if it worked